# mysql pagination with left join and LIKE -> super slow

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

So  - I have 2 tables:

`entries` table:

```
id - Primary key
meta_keys VARCHAR 20
meta_desc VARCHAR 20
..some other unimportant columns...
```

`headwords` table:

```
id -  Primary key
fk_entries_id - foreign key refers to entries(id)
headword_text VARCHAR(200)
..some other unimportant columns...
```

So entries might have multiple headwords - right. So I'm just trying to paginate over entries that have certain word in their headwords. The only query that I came up with requires a LEFT JOIN and then LIKE and is kinda slow.

```
SELECT entries.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT headwords.headword_text SEPARATOR ' ') AS hw 
FROM entries 
LEFT JOIN headwords ON (entries.id = headwords.fk_entries_id) 
GROUP BY entries.id
HAVING hw LIKE '%dog%' 
LIMIT 20,20;
```

Seeking for an advice to speed up this approach.

EDIT> WAIT - would this be a wrong query?:

```
SELECT entries.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT headwords.headword_text SEPARATOR ' ') AS hw 
FROM entries 
LEFT JOIN headwords 
ON (entries.id = headwords.fk_entries_id) 
WHERE headwords.headword_text LIKE 'dog%' 
GROUP BY entries.id;
```

Comment: Sounds like an excellent case for a REAL full-text search engine. See http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql  (posted as comment, because it doesnt actully answer your question as such. Sidesteps it instead :)

Comment: Hey Barry! I use sphinx on frontend, but I don't wanna use it in the backend though as thta's on the separate server and then I'd have to also update RT indexes in addition to CRUD.

Comment: well even using mysqls built in Full-text search support might help here.

Comment: For your last query you just added, suggest adding the output of EXPLAIN om the query.

Comment: Full-text search support > it only works from mysql 5.6, I'm stuck with 5.5 on ubuntu 12.04 servers:)

Comment: another point is you have 'LEFT JOIN' - you really want 'INNER JOIN' because your 'WHERE' is on the `headwords` table, you only want entities that match headwords table. INNER JOIN mysql should be able to optimize slightly better

Answer (score 0):

You should use an IN comparison to avoid all that string concatenation and searching you are doing:

```
select e.*
from entries e
where e.id IN (
   select distinct fk_entries_id
   from headwords
   where headword_text like '%dog%'
)
order by e.id
limit 20,20;
```

Also, you can improve it's performance farther if you are only matching the START of the word by replacing '%dog%' with 'dog%'.  This will speed up performance further since you no longer need to account for the added text in front of each header word.

Comment: This improved it somewhat: 25 rows in set (0.58 sec) vs 25 rows in set (0.38 sec) (single % mode) - still seems a bit slow'ish as this is unlodaded dev server. There are ~40000 rows in both entries and headwords table

Comment: Wait - I can probably just use WHERE after ON clause - and then that will be super fast unless I'm missing something.

Comment: There is also the question of having a index on headword_text. Do you?

Comment: Yes - I do have an index!:)

Comment: Sorry long weekend with no internet - .58 to .38 seems like pretty good improvement (~33% improvement).  If you have indexed the heck out of it already, then short of full text search, I don't think you will get it faster.  Good luck!